# Asp.net MVC Ajax.ActionLink send ViewData.Model to the Action with last User inputs

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to send ViewData.model to Special action with the last user data entry.

I mean, the Edit form is showed to the User, User input values to some fields, when he/she will click on the Ajax.ActionLink, I am supposed to get my Model with the last modified in the action.

I am sending ViewData.Model to the Action with the below code, but i can not catch last changed value.

```
<%=Ajax.ActionLink("Contact this person Ajax", "MyAction", "MyController",ViewData.Model, new AjaxOptions {  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "thickbox" })%>
```

and My Action Code:

```
      [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public PartialViewResult MyAction(MyModel model){
.....}
```

What shall i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of `Ajax.ActionLink`. With `Ajax.ActionLink` you need to manually pass all the values. With `Ajax.BeginForm` all the input fields inside this form will be sent with the request and inside your action you will be able to rebind the model.